# How can I tell if my website is causing the browser to crash and burn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, crash

I have written a website that relies heavily on Javascript/jQuery and HTML5.

Unfortunately I occasionally experience complete browser melt downs. Because the entire browser dies on me I am finding it very hard to pin point if I have done something to cause this.

I have no infinite loops, Ive been carefully trying to make sure there are no memory leaks. Another problem is that I cant recreate the issue on command. Doing the same things in the same way and order as what caused the crash last time, wont make it crash again.

I am not entirely convinced the issue is my website, but it does seem to happen more often when I am browsing the site. These crashes have occurred in the latest stable released of Firefox and Chrome.

Is there anything I can do to get some valuable debugging information when the browser dies?

And is there any software additional to things like FireBug which I can use to specifically hunt down any memory leaks?

Comment: if this question is off topic here, can anyone suggest a stack exchange site where it would be on topic?

Comment: Have you tried chrome's built-in task manager? (shift+esc)

Comment: Well nobody can help much without you first identifying the code in your pages that's causing the issue. A browser *crash* is sort-of, by definition, a browser *bug*, because it effectively means that you've found a denial-of-service attack. Thus it's not the sort of thing that ordinary web developer tools expect to address.

Comment: gdb has helped with some application crash. From the stackdump after crash, you may get some idea what went wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does your firefox try to send a crash report to mozilla? If so, I believe you can view your own crash reports somewhere on the mozilla site. I'd look it up, but am running out of time here.

p.s. lacking reputation to make this comment, it is answer instead >.>